# Using an if statement to pass through variables ot further functions for python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am a biologist that is just trying to use python to automate a ton of calculations, so I have very little experience.

I have a very large array that contains values that are formatted into two columns of observations. Sometimes the observations will be the same between the columns:
v1,v2
x,y
a,b
a,a
x,x

In order to save time and effort I wanted to make an if statement that just prints 0 if the two columns are the same and then moves on. If the values are the same there is no need to run those instances through the downstream analyses.

This is what I have so far just to test out the if statement. It has yet to recognize any instances where the columns are equivalen.

Script:

```
mylines=[]

with open('xxxx','r') as myfile:
    for myline in myfile:
        mylines.append(myline)             ##reads the data into the two column format mentioned above

rang=len(open ('xxxxx,'r').readlines( ))   ##returns the number or lines in the file

for x in range(1, rang):

    li = mylines[x]         ##selected row as defined by x and the number of lines in the file
    spit = li.split(',',2)  ##splits the selected values so they can be accessed seperately
    print(spit[0])          ##first value
    print(spit[1])          ##second value

    if spit[0] == spit[1]:
        print(0)
    else:
        print('Issue')
```

Output:
192Alhe52
192Alhe52

Issue  ##should be 0

188Alhe48
192Alhe52

Issue

191Alhe51
192Alhe52

Issue

How do I get python to recgonize that certain observations are actually equal?

Comment: I would guess that there are whitespaces left in one of the split parts. You may use `strip()` to remove them, e.g. `if spit[0].strip() == spit[1].strip()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read the values and store them in the array, you can be storing `'\n'` as well, which is a break line character, so your array actually looks like this

```
print(mylist)
['x,y\n', 'a,b\n', 'a,a\n', 'x,x\n']
```

To work around this issue, you have to use `strip()`, which will remove this character and occasional blank spaces in the end of the string that would also affect the comparison

```
mylines.append(myline.strip())
```

You shouldn't use `rang=len(open ('xxxxx,'r').readlines( ))`, because you are reading the file again

```
rang=len(mylines)
```

There is a more readable, pythonic way to replicate your `for`

```
for li in mylines[1:]:
    spit = li.split(',')
    if spit[0] == spit[1]:
        print(0)
    else:
        print('Issue')
```

Or even

```
for spit.split(',') in mylines[1:]:
    if spit[0] == spit[1]:
        print(0)
    else:
        print('Issue')
```

will iterate on the array `mylines`, starting from the first element.
Also, if you're interested in python packages, you should have a look at pandas. Assuming you have a csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('xxxx')
for i, elements in df.iterrows():
    if elements['v1'] == elements['v2']:
        print('Equal')
    else:
        print('Different')
```

will do the trick. If you need to modify values and write another file

```
df.to_csv('nameYouWant')
```

Answer (score 0):

For one, your issue with the equals test might be because iterating over lines like this also yields the newline character. There is a string function that can get rid of that, `.strip()`. Also, your argument to split is `2`, which splits your row into three groups - but that probably doesn't show here. You can avoid having to parse it yourself when using the csv module, as your file presumably is that:

```
import csv

with open("yourfile.txt") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)  # skip header
    for first, second in reader:
        print(first)
        print(second)
        if first == second:
            print(0)
        else:
            print("Issue")
```